# Function not being called when I return to the page

Tags: javascript

I have two images, the first image can be any size and I'd like the second image, right beside it to be the same height as the first image. I wrote the following code:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#first").load(function() {
      var imgheight = $(this).height();
      $("#first_papers").css("height", imgheight); 
    });
  });
</script>
```

The above code works fine. The problem is that when I visit another page on the site and then return to the main page the function doesn't seem to be called. What happens insteadis that the second image is appearing at its full height instead of the shorter height of the first image.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For consistent behavior whenever the page loads I would take it out of the anonymous function its in and put it in a `$(document).ready` function.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#first").load(function() {
            var imgheight = $(this).height();
            $("#first_papers").css("height", imgheight); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

This should make it execute whenever your page loads no matter when/how you navigate to it.

Comment: I replaced my code with yours and I'm still getting the same issue. Unfortunately I can't share a link to the page because its secured page.

Comment: @michelle can you share more of the code or replicate the bug in a www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @ryan - here is the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/michelleali/scDJv/. I can't seem to get it to work at all there.